# CSS lists inside list not aligning horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am making a horizontal menu, the four sections should be next to each other, the sausage rolls, fries, wings, spinach pinwheels, and garlic bread should ve vertical, but horizontally next to the next list. I checked every single question the alert suggested is similar or the same to this one but not a single one helps, maybe there's something wrong with my HTML?

```html
<form method="post" action="menu.php">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Sausage Rolls</li>
        <li>Fries</li>
        <li>Wings</li>
        <li>Spinach Pinwheels</li>
        <li>Garlci Bread</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Instant Pot Chicken</li>
        <li>Salmon Pattles</li>
        <li>Callco Cabbage</li>
        <li>Bacon Wrappend Jalapeno</li>
        <li>Potato Mash</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Edible Cookie Dough</li>
        <li>Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
        <li>Cheesecake</li>
        <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        <li>Brownies</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Water</li>
        <li>Juice</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="order" value="Order">
</form>
```

Comment: I used one method but the lists would then go downwards like a flight of stairs.

Comment: attach your stylesheet here

Comment: You can add either `float` or `flex` to get the desired result. It would be better if you can post your CSS code here as well, if you are getting any other issues.

Answer (score 4):

use css `flex-box` property , here I  added `display:flex` to your parent `ul` tag

and it's working fine.

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  padding : 0px;
 }
form>ul{
   display:flex;
  }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="menu.php">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Sausage Rolls</li>
        <li>Fries</li>
        <li>Wings</li>
        <li>Spinach Pinwheels</li>
        <li>Garlci Bread</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Instant Pot Chicken</li>
        <li>Salmon Pattles</li>
        <li>Callco Cabbage</li>
        <li>Bacon Wrappend Jalapeno</li>
        <li>Potato Mash</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Edible Cookie Dough</li>
        <li>Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
        <li>Cheesecake</li>
        <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        <li>Brownies</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Water</li>
        <li>Juice</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="order" value="Order">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using `display: flex;`:

```html
<style>
  li.lists {
    float: left;
  }
  
  form ul.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<form method="post" action="menu.php">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li class="lists">
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Sausage Rolls</li>
        <li>Fries</li>
        <li>Wings</li>
        <li>Spinach Pinwheels</li>
        <li>Garlci Bread</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lists">
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Instant Pot Chicken</li>
        <li>Salmon Pattles</li>
        <li>Callco Cabbage</li>
        <li>Bacon Wrappend Jalapeno</li>
        <li>Potato Mash</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lists">
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Edible Cookie Dough</li>
        <li>Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
        <li>Cheesecake</li>
        <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        <li>Brownies</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lists">
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Water</li>
        <li>Juice</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="order" value="Order">
</form>
```

Comment: You had solved the problem using float without using flex. But it's old method now flex is trending.

Answer (score 0):

Here are another way using without *`flex-box`*

Here i added  `display: table;` into `ul`, or added `display: table-cell;` into `li`

And it's working fine.

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  padding : 0px;
 }
form>ul {
    display: table;
}
form>ul>li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
  <form method="post" action="menu.php">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Sausage Rolls</li>
        <li>Fries</li>
        <li>Wings</li>
        <li>Spinach Pinwheels</li>
        <li>Garlci Bread</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Instant Pot Chicken</li>
        <li>Salmon Pattles</li>
        <li>Callco Cabbage</li>
        <li>Bacon Wrappend Jalapeno</li>
        <li>Potato Mash</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Edible Cookie Dough</li>
        <li>Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
        <li>Cheesecake</li>
        <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        <li>Brownies</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="menus">
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Beer</li>
        <li>Water</li>
        <li>Juice</li>
        <li>Coffee</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="order" value="Order">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `display: flex` , simplified html.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
<style type="text/css">
.menus
{
   float: left;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  
}
.btn-submit {
    clear:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="menu.php">

<ul class="menus">
    <li>Sausage Rolls</li>
    <li>Fries</li>
    <li>Wings</li>
    <li>Spinach Pinwheels</li>
    <li>Garlci Bread</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menus">
    <li>Instant Pot Chicken</li>
    <li>Salmon Pattles</li>
    <li>Callco Cabbage</li>
    <li>Bacon Wrappend Jalapeno</li>
    <li>Potato Mash</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menus">
    <li>Edible Cookie Dough</li>
    <li>Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
    <li>Cheesecake</li>
    <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
    <li>Brownies</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menus">
    <li>Wine</li>
    <li>Beer</li>
    <li>Water</li>
    <li>Juice</li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
<div class="btn-submit"><input type="submit" name="order" value="Order"></div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```